Trouble in flutter and android studio installation
I am trying to install the latest flutter and android studio, however, I am facing issue during android studio installation.
I have installed git and also downloaded flutter and extracted the flutter in C:\ drive and added the path of the flutter bin folder in system environment variables.
Now, I have installed Android Studio and when checking with the command "flutter doctor", it is showing error of "cmdline tools" not installed as shown in the screenshot below. However,I have already installed the "cmdline tools from the Android studio SDK tools section as is being shown, but, still the error is being shown.
I am not able to find out where the error is happening, hence, would appreciate any help.



I tried checking from multiple videos and online forums but couldn't find the exact issue or solution.

Have you tried to manually add the platform tools and cmdline-tools directories on your Path?
I think that this can solve your problem. On this Stackoverflow question the user was using Ubuntu. Just make sure that on you Windows the paths will remain the same and add them to your Path env var.

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools export
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/ export
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.1.0-rc1/ export
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator/bin64/


I have now added the paths as mentioned above, but still the same issue coming.

have you checked if the path os correct? the binary files exists in thes repositories?

Yes, I have added the env variable paths as shown in the screenshot above. I have added the screenshot.
